# How do I spell out period using Google voice recognition?

Tags: voice-recognition, google-voice-actions

While using voice-to-text to transcribe notes to Google Keep, I realized whenever I said "period" it would put out the punctuation mark. This is great 99% of the time, but sometimes I need to say period, e.g. "3rd period," or even "comma."

While a relatively easy workaround is to use the plural form "commas/periods" and edit things later, I'm wondering if there is something in the settings that I missed that can be tweaked. Settings::Language and Keyboard::(Google voice typing or Text-to-speech output) are the two places I looked.

Comment: What about spelling out the word `"P-e-r-I-o-d"` it works for my. Android nougat 7.0. Also maybe use the UK English version with full stop for period instead. Are any of those acceptable?

Comment: These both work for me as well. It works for slash, too. For some reason, Android puts the spaces if you try to spell out comma. So it can't be 100 % perfectly generalized. But it works for the two most likely words that voice to text might see as a command. I had tried this for some weirdly spelled words, but I never thought to use it for common words. Thanks so much!